# iOS passing an int object into Coco2D CCLayer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

On the viewcontroller file I call the CCLayer

```
 [director_ runWithScene:[game1 scene]];
```

game1 is a CCLayer, inside the

```
+ (CCScene *)scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    game1 *layer = [game node];
    [scene addChild:layer];

    return scene;
}



- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
    }
    ..
}
```

In the original viewcontroller I try to pass an int object to the game1 scene by 
writing a new class function inside game1

```
 @synthesize point;

+ (void)setPoint:(int)point_
{
    point = point_;
}
```

but I got an error saying the class function setPoint cannot set an instance var.

So how do I pass an int value from viewcontroller to the game1 scene?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't access instance variables from class methods. In a class method, the method itself has no information about on which particular instance of the class should set the variable (it simply doesn't make sense).

What you have to do is have a reference to the particular scene instance (e. g. by assigning it to a property) and then call `[game1 setPoint:point];`

P. s.: you need only one of `@synthesize point` and a manual implementation of `- setPoint:` (assuming your property is not read-only).

Comment: I don't have to instantiate game 1 before because I just did  [director_ runWithScene:[game1 scene]];   so if I have to create an instance I just do   game1* mygame=[game1 alloc] init]; [game1 setpoint:point];  [director_ runwithscene:[game1 scene]];

Comment: @jasonwhite then now you **will have to** instantiate game1 before.

Comment: and change the + (CCScene *)scene to -(CCscene*) scene